# python selenium choice list box

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

can you help me to choice list box webdrive selenium
i want to choice country for example Iraq
this website
https://auth.uber.com/v2/?breeze_local_zone=dca1&inAuthSessionID=c2feba2d-3285-4235-bd69-fceee407797f&next_url=https%3A%2F%2Fpostmates.com%2Flogin-redirect%2F%3Fcampaign%3Dsignin_universal_link%26guest_mode%3Dfalse%26marketing_vistor_id%3D8740ed6f-7a0f-48ba-b579-db10bcae837c%26redirect%3D%252F%26session%3Dcancelled%26session%3Dcancelled%26session%3Dcancelled%26session%3Dcancelled&state=xr9NjFU-bmOZtv1ciIn1dLB9nOMwSubmmscBTCqPws0%3D&x-uber-client-name=postmates-web&fbclid=IwAR0lEn7lOuqNTQ8j8tHG4mSldYvHGQkEuC7JMMoE6Ur8rsTgP7ni841VkJ0

code HTML

```
<ul role="listbox" aria-label="Choose a country code" tabindex="0" data-baseweb="menu" id="1" aria-multiselectable="false" class="fe dd ek el ev em ff fg ep e9 dg dh di dj f6 fh fi fj"><li role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" id="221val-0" class="db cl dc cm dd ae fk c0 ef fl dv dw el en eo e9 ep fi aj fm"><div class="bb ae aj"><span data-iso="AF" class="c4 c7"></span></div><div class="bb">Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)</div><div class="bc fn">+93</div></li><li role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" id="221val-1" class="db cl dc cm dd ae fk c0 ef fl dv dw el en eo e9 ep fi aj fm"><div class="bb ae aj"><span data-iso="AL" class="c4 c7"></span></div><div class="bb">Albania (Shqipëri)</div><div class="bc fn">+355</div></li><li role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" id="221val-2" class="db cl dc cm dd ae fk c0 ef fl dv dw el en eo e9 ep fi aj fm"><div class="bb ae aj"><span data-iso="DZ" class="c4 c7"></span></div><div class="bb">Algeria (‫الجزائر‬‎)</div><div class="bc fn">+213</div></li><li role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" id="221val-3" class="db cl dc cm dd ae fk c0 ef fl dv dw el en eo e9 ep fi aj fm"><div class="bb ae aj"><span data-iso="AS" class="c4 c7"></span></div><div class="bb">American Samoa</div><div class="bc fn">+1684</div></li><li role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" id="221val-4" class="db cl dc cm dd ae fk c0 ef fl dv dw el en eo e9 ep fi aj fm">
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can use the below code to click on dropdown and then choose Iraq:*

***//Click on DropDown***

```
drop_Down= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='c4 c5'])[1]")))
drop_Down.click()
```

***//Choose Iraq***

```
drp_value= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'')]")))
drp_value.click()
```